# how can I make usable source inside bash script?

Tags: python, bash, deployment

I am writing a deployment script for Django, but at the moment to reload `~/.bashrc` it doesn't found the `SECRET_KEY`because it didn't reload it, but I also tried with `.`, and `source` seems not to work. any other idea? my os is making use of `bash`

```
echo $0
bash
```

```
#!/bin/bash
token=$(/usr/bin/python3 token.py)
env=$(/usr/bin/python3 env.py)

echo -e " " >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxxxx' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="xxxxxxx"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export SECRET_KEY="'$token'"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
echo "$env" # line 19 error
```

output
`deploy.sh: line 19: None: command not found`

```
import os

# Get environment variables
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
print(SECRET_KEY)
```

Comment: which line has number 19 ?

Comment: it is the `$env` as you can see the snip

Comment: you run script `env.py` in third line before `"source"` (before you reload bashrc) and display result after `"source"` so you get `None` instead of `SECRET KEY`. You should run at the end `env=$(/usr/bin/python3 env.py)`

Comment: if I move env after source, and make `$env` i get the same

Comment: you forgot `"` at the end of `EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxxxx`

Comment: when I add `"` at the end of line `EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxxxx` then it creates correct code in `.bashrc` and it works for me

Comment: BTW: you should also check `echo $token` after `token=$(/usr/bin/python3 token.py)`. Maybe `token.py` returns `None`

Comment: @furas it returns none because `.bashrc` isn't reloaded because it doesn't exist `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: it works for me but it needs two things: (1) add `"` at the end of `EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxxxx` because without `"` it get error in bashrc and it never execute last line `export SECRET_KEY="..."`. You simply forgot closing `"` in `"xxxxxxx` and it treasts string `"xxxxxxx ... SECRET_KEY="` as one long value - not three different values (BTW: you can use `cat ~/.bashrc` to see what you get in `~/.bashrc`. (2) run `env=$(/usr/bin/python3 env.py)` after `source ~/.bashrc` because if you run it before `source ~/.bashrc` then it try to get `SECRET_KEY` before you create it.